# Mudar a cor do panel ao passar o mouse

Tags: javascript, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Considerando o seguinte código, (exemplo do site do bootStrap):

```
<div class="panel panel-danger">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">
      Panel Title
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Preciso mudar este panel-danger para outro panel, exemplo: panel-info, quando passar o mouse por ele.

Comment: Deve copiar o colar o codigo para que seja mais facil para nós o ajudarmos sff.

Comment: Bem vindo ao SO Rodrigo! Evite postar a imagem do código, poste o código. As formatações são bem flexíveis veja [Aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Depois da uma olhada nesta [discussão](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5149/devemos-cortar-a-mania-das-perguntas-com-imagem-do-código-ao-invés-do-código?cb=1)

Comment: Miguel e Jean... eu tentei colocar o código mas não apareceu... ai coloquei a imagem rsss... mas valeu

Answer (score 1):

Podes alterar com css usando o hover na classe panel-danger ex:

```
.panel-danger:hover {
  background: cor;
}
```

Ou então mudas a class em jQuery com o [mouseover](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) ex:

```js
$(".panel-danger").mouseover(function() {
  $(this).removeClass("panel-danger").addClass("panel-info");
}).mouseout(function() {
  $(this).removeClass("panel-info").addClass("panel-danger");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-danger">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">
      Panel Title
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Se optares por esta opção aconselho a usares um ID em vez da própria class.

Answer (score 0):

A resposta do Skramewell é muito boa, mas desta forma vai fazer a mudança todas as vezes que declarar a classe `panel panel-danger`.

Crie uma classe personalizada ou um ID para usar nestes casos. Eu vou criar uma classe chamada `hover-personalizado`, assim você usa ela quando quiser fazer esta mudança. Exemplo:

```js
$(".hover-personalizado").mouseover(function() {
  $(this).removeClass("panel-danger").addClass("panel-info");
}).mouseout(function() {
  $(this).removeClass("panel-info").addClass("panel-danger");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-danger hover-personalizado">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">
      Panel Title
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

```js
$(".panel-danger").mouseover(function() {
  $(this).removeClass("panel-danger").addClass("panel-info");
}).mouseout(function() {
  $(this).removeClass("panel-info").addClass("panel-danger");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-danger">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">
      Panel Title
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).